# Wordpress image caption shortcodes showing on posts (not rendering as captions)

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to fix an issue with a custom WordPress theme that is rendering image captions inline on posts. My WP knowledge is spotty, so, I'm not quite sure where I should be looking.

Here's the code that's showing posts:

```
<?


$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'post' ),
    'meta_key' => 'event_date', // name of custom field
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

// The Query
$blogQuery = new WP_Query( $args );

  while ( $blogQuery->have_posts() ) {
      $blogQuery->the_post();
      $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('event_date'));
      $today = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', date('Ymd'));

      if($date > $today){

          echo '<div class="blog-entry">';
          echo '<h3 class="wonk green-nav">Event: ';
          echo get_the_title().'</h3>';

            if(get_field('update_type') == 'event'){

                echo '<h4>';    
                echo $date->format('l, F jS, Y. ');
                the_field('event_time');
                echo '</h4>';

            }


          echo '<p>' .get_the_content().'</p>';
          echo '</div>';
          }

      }

 wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Here's a screenshot showing what's on the front-end...

[image: screenshot of shortcodes being rendered in post text]

Comment: Check your functions.php file, someone may be unregistering 'img_caption_shortcode'.   

Do you have the same problem if you replace get_the_content() with the_content()?

Comment: Where's the code for the shortcode? Post all the code, and then we can see what's actually happening. Also, can we have a link to the actual page where this is happening...

Comment: That code doesn't appear to be for your shortcode at all. That looks like something else entirely to me.

Comment: Is this showing like this in the actual post / page or on the blog overview page? It's clear so far that the shortcode isn't being registered at which point this content is being displayed. So either the content is showed in a widget or as an excerpt (where shortcodes don't fire by default) OR the relevant shortcode plugin has been disabled.

Answer (score 4):

Shyamin's Answer is a potential solution, but I would like to explain more in depth about what is really going on.

[In the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) for the `the_content()` function you can see Wordpress is actually using `get_the_content()` then using a handy function called `apply_filters( 'the_content', $content)` [Docs here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/).

This function is the reason `the_content()` renders your editor content correctly as compared to `get_the_content()`. It is applying all of the filters added for `the_content` hook. Long story short, one of the filters added to that hook is `do_shortcode()` which renders the shortcodes.

[Here is a neat blog post](https://themehybrid.com/weblog/how-to-apply-content-filters) I found talking a little more about this as well as, how to create your own `apply_filters` hook and adding your own filters to mimic what `the_content()` does to the raw content.

**So your 2 solutions:** (Given that you have no other issues preventing the shortcode from rendering)

1. If your code can handle it, simply use `the_content()` instead of `echo get_the_content()`
2. If you require more advanced control of the content editor data, then store your `'<p>' .get_the_content().'</p>';` in a variable like `$content_data` for example. and then in your echo statement use: `echo apply_filters('the_content', $content_data);`

This should solve your issues!

Comment: Thank you sir - your point 2 worked wonders. Something I have learnt today which is clearly crucial to wordpress development!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my custom theme. Dunno why is this happening but I found a way to make it work. So putting this comment to inform others :)

just try load post content using the_content() function if you are using get_the_content() :) the_content() will render the correct html tags for the caption short codes in WordPress. Dunno why is it happening :/